Updating one table with second table with dplyr
I have two data frames. The first one is named first_df and the second one is named second_df. Now, I want to update the data from the second data frame to the first one.
 # First data frame
library(dplyr)
    first_df <- data.frame(
                        ShortName = c("A", "B", "C"),
                        t1 = c(0, 0, 0 ),
                        t2 = c(1, 1, 1),
                        t3 = c(2, 2, 2),
                        t4 = c(3, 3, 3)
                      )


 # Second data frame
    second_df <- data.frame(
                    ShortName = c("A", "B", "C"),
                    Year = c(2024, 2025, 2026 ),
                    Value=c(0, 5, 10)
                  )
    


The update should be in such a way that columns t1, t2, t3, and t4 correspond to the years 2024, 2025, 2026, and 2027.If the year in the value parameter is 2026, it means that the value will be applied from 2026 onwards, which includes the year 2027 as well.
In the end, the table should look like the table shown in the following image.

Can someone help me to do this with dplyr ?

The mapping between the years and the t1 to t4 columns is not yet clear to me. Why is t1 in the final df always 0? Why is t2/C 1?

Because A is applied from 2024 or t1 onwards until 2027 or t4

I may have misunderstood, but here is one potential solution:
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

first_df <- data.frame(
  ShortName = c("A", "B", "C"),
  t1 = c(0, 0, 0 ),
  t2 = c(1, 1, 1),
  t3 = c(2, 2, 2),
  t4 = c(3, 3, 3)
)

second_df <- data.frame(
  ShortName = c("A", "B", "C"),
  Year = c(2024, 2025, 2026 ),
  Value=c(0, 5, 10)
)

first_df %>%
  pivot_longer(-ShortName,
               names_to = "timepoint",
               values_to = "original_value") %>%
  mutate(original_year = 2023 + row_number(), .by = ShortName) %>% 
  left_join(second_df, by = join_by(ShortName)) %>%
  mutate(amended_value = ifelse(original_year < Year, original_value, Value)) %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = ShortName,
              names_from = timepoint,
              values_from = amended_value)
#> # A tibble: 3 × 5
#>   ShortName    t1    t2    t3    t4
#>   <chr>     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 A             0     0     0     0
#> 2 B             0     5     5     5
#> 3 C             0     1    10    10

Created on 2024-05-13 with reprex v2.1.0

Glad you solved your problem @silent_hunter. Sorry your question got closed - I think the people who voted against it didn't understand what you wanted to do

1) dplyr/tidyr Join the data frames joining the Year and Value columns from second_df to first_df and then nest that within ShortName.  Now use replace to clobber the appropriate nested columns with Value.  The last 2 lines undo the left_join and nest_by.
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

first_df %>%
  left_join(second_df, "ShortName") %>%
  nest_by(ShortName, Year, Value) %>%
  reframe(data = replace(data, seq(Year - 2023, ncol(data)), Value)) %>%
  unnest(data) %>%
  select(-Year, -Value)

giving
# A tibble: 3 × 5
  ShortName    t1    t2    t3    t4
  <chr>     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 A             0     0     0     0
2 B             0     5     5     5
3 C             0     1    10    10

2) group_modify This approach is similar to (1) but uses uses only dplyr using group_modify instead of nesting.
library(dplyr)

first_df %>%
  left_join(second_df, "ShortName") %>%
  group_by(ShortName) %>%
  group_modify(~ replace(.x, seq(.x$Year-2023, ncol(.x)), .x$Value)) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  select(-Year, -Value) 

3) Base R With base R we have the following compact solution:
out <- first_df
for(i in 1:nrow(out))
  out[i, seq(second_df$Year[i]-2022, ncol(first_df))] <- second_df$Value[i]

